# Android: Have a non-editable EditText, but still have a cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am attempting to make a calculator, and when entering numbers with the GUI, I want users to be able to click in the `EditText` to change the cursor, but not enable the keyboard. Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Simple, use TextView instead. And make it act like EditText.

Comment: @user3466786 use android:cursorVisible="true"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code for that purpose,

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/editext1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
   android:cursorVisible="true">

</EditText>
```

And then,

```
EditText input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
input.setSelection(input.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable the input keyboard of android device.
In that case the best solution would be: (In the Manifest file and the activity construct for the particular activity)

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 

    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

or you can use this to consume the onTouch event:

```
editText_input_field.setOnTouchListener(otl);

private OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // the listener has consumed the event
}
};
```

Here is another example.

```
MyEditor.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
int inType = MyEditor.getInputType(); // backup the input type
MyEditor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); // disable soft input
MyEditor.onTouchEvent(event); // call native handler
MyEditor.setInputType(inType); // restore input type
return true; // consume touch even
}
});
```